# How can I set up a node app (ember app kit) on heroku that reads ENV variables and makes the values available to the application?

Tags: node.js, heroku, ember.js, gruntjs, ember-app-kit

Okay, I'm new to node, and really only just using the node server to serve static js, but I can't find any info on this anywhere.

I'm running an application [ember app kit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit), which gets built to a node `server.js` for deploy, and heroku runs it with `node server.js`.

It uses [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) for building, testing, etc.

I'd like to know how I can specify configuration variables (i.e. authentication tokens) that can be overridden by heroku config variables.

The closest I've been able to get is a custom task that reads environment variables and writes out a json file that gets built into the site (and assigned to a global var).  This works locally, but doesn't take into account heroku configs.

I even wrote a deploy script that gets heroku's configs, exports them as environment variables locally, and does the build--Which *works*, but the configs only get updated on app **deploy**. So if I do a `heroku config:add CONFIG_TEST=test_value`, my app doesn't see that value for `CONFIG_TEST` until the next time I deploy the app.

I'd like for my app to start embedding that config value in the browser JS immediately.

Any way to do this with node the way my app is set up?

Comment: Great question. For sure the custom-task-that-writes-json approach is not what you want, since that json file will end up in source control. That kinda defeats the whole point of using env variables. I've not tried it but one approach might be to generate that json _dynamically_ based on env variables - something like `var apiKey = process.env.API_KEY`

Comment: Well, yes and no.  The json file that gets written out from the environment variables is created at build-time, and compiled in/minified/uglified/whatever with the rest of the static js assets.  It's committed to the repo inasmuch as it gets pushed to **heroku**, but it's never in the actual git repo for the project.

That said, it's still definitely not what I want, because it requires that I actually deploy a build to update the values, which makes no sense as an admin.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what's wrong with simply taking config variables, at run time, from the environment. Use process.env.KEY in your code, and embed that result into whatever template you may have, and serve that as the result.

When you change Heroku config variables your process gets restarted, so it picks up the new values.

Is the problem the fact that you serve *static* files? If so -- can you simply change it so that you use a template engine to do some processing on them before serving?

Comment: Yeah, this is the problem, the instructions for ember app kit just use express to serve up static files so process.env isn't available. I'm not sure how to solve this. The env vars are available during the build process(when you push to heroku) so maybe there's a way to rewrite some vars at that point.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's a solution for ember-app-kit using grunt-sed.

In EMBER_APP_KIT_PROJECT/tasks/options/sed.js

Add something like

```
module.exports = {
    version: {
        path: "./dist/",
        pattern: '{{env.API_BASE_PATH}}',
        replacement: function(){
            return process.env.API_BASE_PATH;
        },
        recursive: true
    }
};
```

then in your code just put

```
"{{env.API_BASE_PATH}}"
```

Now, when you run

```
$ grunt sed
```

it will replace "{{env.API_BASE_PATH}}" with whatever's in the environment variable.